# Problema de sintaxis de la sentencia SQL en Visual Studio C#, con Access

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, visual-studio-2015, ms-access

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion; Este cuatrimestre el profesor nos ha puesto un proyecto en `C#`, manejando la base de datos en `Access` (Uso el Access 16, ya que tengo la licencia del mismo).

El problema es que a la hora de guardar los datos de uno de los alumnos en la base de datos, recibo un error de Visual informándome que la sentencia SQL tiene un error de sentaxis.

Este es el error:

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' en
>   System.Data.dll

Información adicional:

> Error de sintaxis en la instrucción INSERT INTO.

Este es el código de la función:

```
public bool Agregar_Estudiantes(string Codigo, string Apellidos, string Nombres, string Edad, string Direccion, string Correo, string Sexo, string Tel_Res, string Tel_Movil, string Curso, string Mensualidad)
        {

            int Eda = Convert.ToInt32(Edad);
            //Conexion
            OleDbConnection Conexion = new OleDbConnection();
            Conexion.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = D:\\Proyecto Final POO\\Proyecto Final POO\\Proyecto Final POO.mdb; Persist Security Info = false;";

            //Instruccion SQL
            string CadenaSQL = "INSERT INTO Personal (Id, Apellidos, Nombres, Edad, Direccion, Correo, Sexo, Tel_Res, Tel_Movil, Curso, Mensualidad) ";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + " VALUES (  " + Codigo    + ",";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + "          '" + Apellidos + "',";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + "          '" + Nombres   + "',";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + "           " + Eda      + ",";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + "          '" + Direccion + "',";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + "          '" + Correo   + "',";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + "          '" + Sexo     + "',";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + "          '" + Tel_Res  + "',";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + "          '" + Tel_Movil + "',";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + "          '" + Curso     + "',";
            CadenaSQL = CadenaSQL + "          '" + Mensualidad + "')";


            //Crear comando
            OleDbCommand Comando = Conexion.CreateCommand();
            Comando.CommandText = CadenaSQL;

            //Ejecutar la consulta de accion
            Conexion.Open();
            Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Conexion.Close();

            return true;
        }
```

Los datos, son recibidos en un `TexBox`, y enviados desde un `Button`, quien le asigna los valores a la función que arriba he mostrado.

Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Puede deberse a un error en la construcción de tu instrucción SQL `INSERT INTO Personal ...`. _Asumo que estás haciendo una aplicación de consola_, imprime el valor de `CadenaSQL` antes de enviarlo a la base de datos, luego toma el resultado de `CadenaSQL` y pégalo en Access, si te sale el mismo error, es porque no estás creando bien el INSERT.

Comment: Estas seguro que Id es de tipo número, el error podría ser que sea un realidad un campo de texto y tengas que arreglar el tipo de dato o de colocalrle los ' alrededor del valor como en los demás campos

Comment: Estoy trabajando en un windows Form, no en una consola. Te cuento que me dejo guardar el primer alumno en la base de datos, y luego no me comenzo a dar algunos errores que solucione, y ahora estoy atorado en ese.

Comment: Carlos, probare lo que me has comentado, Gracias!

Comment: Hola, probe lo que me ha comentado Carlos, pero recibo el siguiente error en la linea del Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();  y es este: Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' en System.Data.dll

Información adicional: No coinciden los tipos de datos en la expresión de criterios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es una pésima manera de persistir datos, para comenzar no uses una clase Conexión, tarde o temprano te traerá problemas.
Declara la conexión en el archivo App.config, como muestro en este ejemplo:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="default" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Biblioteca\DB\Biblioteca.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Debes de declarar la conexión en un bloque Using...End Using, una buena practica es utilizar parámetros.

```
public static void Guardar(AlumnoEntity alumno)
    {
        using (var cn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()) )
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Alumnos(AlumnoId, Nombre, Direccion, Telefono, Email) VALUES(@AlumnoId, @Nombre, @Direccion, @Telefono, @Email)";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlumnoId", alumno.AlumnoId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", alumno.Nombre);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", alumno.Direccion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", alumno.Telefono);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", alumno.Email);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Revisa este link donde enseñan a programar en capas [Programación en 3 capas](http://joseluisgarciab.blogspot.com/2014/09/programacion-en-3-capas.html), si estas aprendiendo aprende buenas practicas de programación

> **Recomendación:** Al encerrar la declaración del objeto Connection entre un bloque Using ... End Using, nos estaremos asegurando de
>   cerrar la conexión y de destruir los recursos utilizados por el
>   objeto, al finalizar dicho bloque (cuando se ejecute End Using). Con
>   ésto no tenemos que estar pendientes de llamar al método Close (para
>   cerrar la conexión), ni tampoco al método Dispose (para destruir el
>   objeto), por tanto, no es necesario disponer de un procedimiento
>   externo para tales menesteres.

Espero la información brindada sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Lamenteblemente, muchos profesores se van por las maneras mas faciles de enseñar, probare lo que me has comentado.